# WARNINGS during R CMD check

Tags: r, warnings, r-package, roxygen2

i want to create a package. During R CMD check I have faced the following 4 Warnings and 3 Notes as

```
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... NOTE
Malformed Description field: should contain one or more complete sentences.
Standardizable: TRUE
Standardized license specification:
  GPL-2

* checking S3 generic/method consistency ... WARNING
plot:
  function(x, ...)
plot.Lap:
  function(y, k, h)

plot:
  function(x, ...)
plot.rig:
  function(y, k, h)

See section 'Generic functions and methods' in the 'Writing R
Extensions' manual.

Found the following apparent S3 methods exported but not registered:
  plot.Lap plot.rig
See section 'Registering S3 methods' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
manual.
* checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
NSR: no visible global function definition for 'IQR'
mselap: no visible global function definition for 'dexp'
mselap: no visible global function definition for 'dgamma'
mselap: no visible global function definition for 'var'
mserig: no visible global function definition for 'dexp'
mserig: no visible global function definition for 'dgamma'
mserig: no visible global function definition for 'var'
plot.Lap: no visible global function definition for 'density'
plot.Lap: no visible global function definition for 'plot'
plot.Lap: no visible global function definition for 'lines'
plot.Lap: no visible global function definition for 'legend'
plot.rig: no visible global function definition for 'density'
plot.rig: no visible global function definition for 'plot'
plot.rig: no visible global function definition for 'lines'
plot.rig: no visible global function definition for 'legend'
Undefined global functions or variables:
  IQR density dexp dgamma legend lines plot var
Consider adding
  importFrom("graphics", "legend", "lines", "plot")
  importFrom("stats", "IQR", "density", "dexp", "dgamma", "var")
to your NAMESPACE file.

* checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING
LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
LaTeX errors found:
! LaTeX Error: File `inconsolata.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.276 

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
* checking PDF version of manual without hyperrefs or index ...Warning: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.3/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" Rd2pdf  --batch --no-preview --build-dir="C:/Users/Intag/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpq8TzUZ/Rd2pdf34453a4139c" --no-clean -o  AsyKD-manual.pdf  "C:/Users/Intag/Documents/AsyKD.Rcheck/AsyKD"' had status 1
 OK
* checking for code which exercises the package ... WARNING
No examples, no tests, no vignettes
* DONE
Status: 4 WARNINGs, 3 NOTEs
```

I tried the existing Answers related to this but its not working for all. And my package works with no problem. Could someone please tell me what might be wrong with my package?

Comment: Are `plot.Lap` and `plot.rig` meant to be S3 methods?

Comment: yes in command "plot.Lap" i used plot()

Comment: should I change the function name to resolve this problem, like change to graphlap() and graphrig()???

Comment: Yes, change the function names. Function names of the form `<generic function>.<S3 object name>` are special in R. See for example https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html.

Comment: and what about other Warnings and Notes? Specially "checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING" and "* checking PDF version of manual without hyperrefs or index ...Warning:"...

Comment: `Malformed Description field: should contain one or more complete sentences.`: Write at least one full sentence, ending with a period. `LaTeX errors`: Install the missing style file. `No examples, no tests, no vignettes`: add one of those.

Comment: LaTeX errors: Install the missing style file.  how to perform this, described method on this site recommended to search the path... but how to search the path or install the files. Kindly share the link to install required files. and for No examples, no tests, no vignettes: add one of those. any 1 example in any 1 function() is enough or 1-1 example in all functions()

Comment: Please consult the documentation for your TeX distribution (MikTeX, MacTex, TexLive ...)

Comment: I have no idea about this(TeX distribution (MikTeX, MacTex, TexLive ...)). Can you please explain comprehensively.

Comment: Not without further information. Which operating system do you use? Which TeX distribution do you use? Concerning the missing examples: The message will disapear if you add a single example/test/vignette. It is "good practice" to add more, though.

Comment: @RalfStubner  package "knitr" can handle this problem?

Comment: I do not see the connection to `knitr`.

Comment: @RalfStubner I realized now I have nothing installation related to LaTeX. I am using Windows 7. So now what should I do (which soft-wares to be installed) and how to make link with Rstudio that my Package check smoothly.

Comment: If you don't have a TeX distribution yet, [TinyTeX](https://yihui.name/tinytex/) is the simplest solution.